# Is it possible to accelerate GTK with opengles

Tags: opengl-es, gtk

Is it possible to hardware accelerate the rendering of GTK with OpenglES2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You can put GtkWidgets into the OpenGL scenegraph Clutter using the Clutter-gtk module, but Gtk still draws using cairo and then uploads it to the GFX card as a texture, so there's not a lot of acceleration for just normal windows.